# How to run the bot cli on a serverless architecture?

Tags: botframework, serverless

it is possible to run the bot cli on a serverless microservice like architecture? Such as Aws Lambda and Azure Functions.

To install on my machine, first I need to have node/npm installed. Then I run this command:

```
npm i -g
```

It is possible to have a fully functional bot framework cli on a linux stateless environmen such as aws lambda? If so, there is any particular thing that I need to do to install it?
I know in advance that lambda limits the folders which I have access (i only can write at the /tmp folder, for instance).

Also, I have the option to attach a .zip containing the node modules folder if I want.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

did you try installing the bf cli package and run a command you'd like to run?

Comment: Welcome to the community :) It's a fair question, but if you're looking for clarification it's often best to leave a comment under the question; best to hold off writing an answer until you have the information you need.